# Autoresizing issue of UICollectionViewCell contentView's frame in Storyboard prototype cell (Xcode 6, iOS 8 SDK) happens when running on iOS 7 only

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, xcode6, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 3, iOS 8 SDK. Build Target iOS 7.0 using Swift. Please refer to my problem step by step with screenshots below.

I have a UICollectionView in Storyboard. 1 Prototype UICollectionViewCell which contains 1 label in the centre (no autoresizing rule). Purple background was to mark a contentView that is generated in runtime by the Cell I guess. That view will be resized properly base on my UICollectionViewLayoutDelegate eventually, but not on iOS 7. Notice that I'm using Xcode 6 and the problem only happens on iOS 7.

When I build the app on iOS 8. Everything is okay.

**Note: Purple is the *contentView*, Blue is my UIButton with rounded corner.**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDNDY.png]

However, on iOS 7, all the subViews inside the Cell suddenly shrink to the frame of (0,0,50,50) and never conforms to my Autoresizing rule anymore.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOZH9.png]

I assume this is a bug in iOS 8 SDK or Swift or maybe Xcode?

---

**Update 1:** This problem still exists in the official Xcode 6.0.1 ! The best work around is like what KoCMoHaBTa suggested below by setting the frame in cellForItem of the cell (You have to subclass your cell though). It turned out that this is a incompatibility between iOS 8 SDK and iOS 7 (check ecotax's answer below quoted from Apple).

**Update 2:**
Paste this code at the beginning of your **cellForItem** and things should be okay:

```
/** Xcode 6 on iOS 7 hot fix **/
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
/** End of Xcode 6 on iOS 7 hot fix **/
```

Comment: I found out that this problem still exists in Xcode 6 Beta 5. Anyone experienced this too?

Comment: I am struggling with this right now in my project.  iOS 7 and iOS 8 built using Xcode 5 look fine.  iOS 8 built using Xcode 6 beta 6 looks fine.  iOS 7 built using Xcode 6 beta 6 is having the problem you are describing.  Using Reveal I can see that my UICollectionViewCell has been properly sized.  But the cell's contentView was not resized, even though it's parent, the UICollectionViewCell has Autoresize Subviews turned on.  The size of the contentView is set to what the storyboard has.  I am not using autolayout in this project.  My project is completely objective-c.

Comment: I just wanted to add that this issue still exists as of Xcode 6 / iOS 8 GM seed. @DanielPlamann's answer to force the `contentView` to resize with the cell works fine to workaround the problem. I guess that in iOS 8 Apple changed something about the way cell content views are handled when created in Interface Builder (which is still a bit of a black box anyway). But the fact that it changes behaviour when targeting iOS 7 is surely a bug.

Comment: Same here with Xcode 6 GM, auto layout and a nib-based cell. I fix it by pinning the `contentView` edges to the cell edges.

Comment: Yeah, this is not good. I don't want to put this workaround into a production app at all. Have anyone of you filed this as bug report yet? I'm afraid they don't take this seriously enough.

Comment: @sergiou87 how did you manage to pin the `contentView` to the edges via the nib when `UICollectionViewCell`s don't show the `contentView` in the nib?

Comment: @Acey unfortunately that has to be done in code :-\ We're using a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` as base class for our custom cells.

Comment: Well, in fact it's not unfortunate, because doing it this way we avoid having to do that for every cell :D

Comment: @Acey I just updated the best solution, either you're using nib or not. Putting the block of code in cellForItem is the safest way.

Comment: Happened both on Xcode 6.0 (from AppStore) AND Xcode 6.1 Beta for Yosemite. 'Update 2' works like charm. I just spent half a day on that...

Comment: Apple appears to have fixed this problem in version 8.1 of the iOS SDK in Xcode 6.1 GM (Build 6A1042b). I removed the hack and my collection view cells were sized correctly. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: Did you test on iOS 7?

Comment: I downloaded xcode 6.1 but still see the same problem in the simulator.

Comment: I never had this issue before iOS 8.1 update, then it started happening (in code compiled with 6.0.1 and also when I recompiled in 6.1). I had to add the workaround to get rid of it.

Comment: None of the solutions still work for me!! Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265576/static-uitableviewcell-subviews-are-resized-incorrectly-was-off-the-screen-ove I got another problem with static cell

Comment: Guys, the sad news is that, Apple still leaves this bug until the latest iOS SDK.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

contentView is broken. It can be also fixed in awakeFromNib

ObjC:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```

Swift3:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
}
```

Comment: Did the trick without self.contentView.frame = self.bounds; Think I need it? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hello Michal, agree with you. But for 100% to be sure, how will it work in next iOSes better to add it I think.

Comment: I like this answer but you need to call [super awakeFromNib];  Also, I'v thinking about adding a check for iOS 7.1 and less, because I'm not sure how adding these resizing masks affects default behavior on iOS8.

Comment: If you're not using nibs or storyboards, this also works if you put it in applyLayoutAttributes:

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am not using Autolayout!! Any assistance?

Comment: How do you create cell? From nib?

Comment: We were seeing an issue with ios 8.x that the collection view cell was not displaying all of it's subviews sometimes.  This fixed our issues, but it is slightly different then the main question.

Comment: I added same code in swift. But still app crashing and showing bad execute error at `layout2.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)` . I added a code in Cell subclass     `self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight`. amy one know how to rectify in swift

Comment: Adding auto resize subviews in the Nib is the real trick. You don't anything else.

Comment: What if storyboard table has static cells?

Comment: How can `contentView` be broken, still?

Answer (score 62):

I encountered the same problem and asked Apple DTS for help. Their reply was:

> In iOS 7, cells’ content views sized themselves via autoresizing
>   masks. In iOS 8, this was changed, cells stopped using the
>   autoresizing masks and started sizing the content view in
>   layoutSubviews. If a nib is encoded in iOS 8 and then decode it on iOS
>   7, you’ll have a content view without an autoresizing mask and no
>   other means by which to size itself. So if you ever change the frame
>   of the cell, the content view won’t follow.
>
> Apps being deploying back to iOS 7 will have to work around this by
>   sizing the content view itself, adding autoresizing masks, or adding
>   constraints.

I guess this means that it's not a bug in XCode 6, but an incompatibility between the iOS 8 SDK and iOS 7 SDK, which will hit you if you upgrade to Xcode 6, because it will automatically start using the iOS 8 SDK.

As I commented before, the workaround Daniel Plamann described works for me. The ones described by Igor Palaguta and KoCMoHaBTa look simpler though, and appear to make sense giving Apple DTS' answer, so I'll try those later.

Comment: This is interesting, but I still hope they fix it. This behavior was only introduced in Xcode 6 GM which added iPhone 6 support.  It was working fine in the earlier betas.  I even brought a project back to an earlier beta after I noticed it and it worked as expected.  I hope everyone files bugs with Apple on this issue.

Comment: @arton I filed a bug report the same day I asked DTS for help. It was closed as a Duplicate of 18312246. Not sure how much this helps.

Comment: I've used the work around by sizing the ContentView and works for me.
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
}

Answer (score 60):

I encountered the same issue and hope that Apple will fix this with the next Xcode version. Meanwhile I use a workaround. In my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass I've just overridden `layoutSubviews` and resize the contentView manually in case the size differs from `collectionViewCell` size.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  BOOL contentViewIsAutoresized = CGSizeEqualToSize(self.frame.size, self.contentView.frame.size);

  if( !contentViewIsAutoresized) {
    CGRect contentViewFrame = self.contentView.frame;
    contentViewFrame.size = self.frame.size;
    self.contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I used a similar work around but I did it in cellForItem / cellForRow which also works.

Comment: This is the best solution. Adding this in cellForItem/cellForRow will cause weird artifacts if you're rotating the device and the cell size changes.

Comment: Hi! I got a problem with this code. For the first time, the boolean contentViewIsAutoresized will be true if it is loaded from storyboard or prototype cell. Only when you do a reloadData, the second it will be correct. So you don't really need to check for the size. Instead just do: self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;

Comment: Confirmed: we should do it in cellForItem or cellForRow because layoutSubviews is only called after the cell is returned. Anything you do before that like drawing stuff will be wrongly calculated.

Comment: Hm, maybe it's better to place `[cell layoutIfNeeded];` in   cellForItem or cellForRow?

Answer (score 38):

Another solution is to set the contentView's size and autoresizing masks in `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` like the following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *cellID = @"CellID";

     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

     // Set contentView's frame and autoresizingMask
     cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
     cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

     // Your custom code goes here

     return cell;
}
```

This works with Auto Layout too, since auto resizing masks are translated to constraints.

Comment: This is a superior solution as it works with any cell type without subclassing and doesn't require changes in multiple places when you are using more than one type of cell in your collection view.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 6.0.1 contentView for  UICollectionViewCell is broken for iOS7 devices.
It can be also fixed by adding proper constraints to UICollectionViewCell and its contentView in awakeFromNib or init methods.

```
        UIView *cellContentView = self.contentView;
        cellContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[cellContentView]|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:0
                                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cellContentView)]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cellContentView]|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:0
                                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cellContentView)]];
```

Comment: Only this works now, you have to do it just for IOS 8, and I have to call it after each dequeue ! But this also is not ideal solution because multiple selection do not work as it should visually...

Comment: Best is to use autolayout really, with this bug you save ironically time by use autolayout event in simple case..

Comment: The mask does not work for me; however setting the constraints works!

Answer (score 4):

This will not work correctly without any of the other mentioned workarounds because of a bug in Xcode 6 GM with how Xcode compiles xib files into the nib format. While I cannot say for 100% certainty it is Xcode related and not having to do with runtime, I'm very confident - here's how I can show it:

1. Build+Run the application in Xcode 5.1.
2. Go to the simulator application's directory and copy the compiled .nib file for the xib you are having issues with.
3. Build+Run the application in Xcode 6 GM.
4. Stop the application.
5. Replace the .nib file in the newly built application's simulator folder with the .nib file created using Xcode 5.1
6. Relaunch the app from the simulator, NOT from Xcode.
7. Your cell loaded from that .nib should work as expected.

I hope everyone who reads this question will file a Radar with Apple. This is a HUGE issue and needs addressing before the final Xcode release.

Edit: In light of [ecotax's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25884832/1569974), I just wanted to update this to say it is now confirmed behavior differences between building in iOS 8 vs iOS 7, but not a bug. My hack fixed the issue because building on iOS 7 added the autoresizing mask to the content view needed to make this work, which Apple no longer adds.

Comment: I'm not sure if they legally can release a different xCode than the GM version

Comment: Haha will they go to jail? =P But in all seriousness, sure they can. They had multiple GM versions for Mavericks if you don't remember. It's not too common but it can happen.

Answer (score 4):

The answers in this post work, what I never understood is **why** it works.

First, there are two "rules":

1. For views created programmatically (Ex. `[UIView new]`), the property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `YES`
2. Views created in interface builder, with AutoLayout enabled, will have the property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `NO`

*The second rule does not seem to apply to top-level views for which you do not define constraints for. (Ex. the content view)*

When looking at a Storyboard cell, notice that the cell does not have its `contentView` exposed. We are not "controlling" the `contentView`, Apple is.

Deep dive into storyboard source code and see how `contentView` cell is defined:

`<view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">`

Now the cell's subviews (notice the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO"`):

`<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NaT-qJ-npL" userLabel="myCustomLabel">`

The `contentView` does not have it's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `NO`. Plus it lacks layout definition, maybe because of what [@ecotax said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-contentviews-frame-in-storyboard-pro/25884832#25884832).

If we look into the `contentView`, it does have an autoresizing mask, but no definition for it:
`<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>`

So there are two conclusions:

1. `contentView` `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `YES`.
2. `contentView` lacks definition of a layout.

This leads us to two solutions which have been talked about.

You can set the autoresizing masks manually in `awakeFromNib`:

```
self.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Or you can set the `contentView` `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` in `awakeFromNib` and define constraints in `- (void)updateConstraints`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the Swift version of @Igor's answer which is accepted and thanks for your nice answer mate.

**First** Goto your `UICollectionViewCell` Subclass and paste the following code as it is inside the class.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
}
```

By the way I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.3. Solution is tested on iOS 9.3 which is working flawlessly.

Thanks, Hope this helped.

Comment: sorry for my bad English, i meant "works like a charm" :)

Comment: @Aznix No issue..:)

Answer (score 2):

In swift, place the following code in the collection view cell subclass:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
  didSet {
    // Fix autolayout constraints broken in Xcode 6 GM + iOS 7.1
    self.contentView.frame = bounds
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. I used to override setBounds in Objective-C to fix this problem (wasn't sure how to write it in Swift). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that there are also issues with `contentView` sizing in iOS 8. It tends to get laid out very late in the cycle, which can cause temporary constraint conflicts. To solve this, I added the following method in a category of `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
- (void)fixupContentView
{
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 80100
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    } else {
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
#endif
#endif
}
```

This method should be called after dequeuing the cell.

Comment: It would be ideal if this method were called automatically. I don't love it, but this could be done by swizzling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: Apple appears to have fixed this problem in version 8.1 of the iOS SDK in Xcode 6.1 GM (Build 6A1042b). Therefore I have updated the code above to not run when using the 8.1 SDK. Once your team has all moved to Xcode 6.1 you can remove this hack entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed doing this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   contentView.superview?.frame = bounds
   super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37611562/1728552)

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure you check the check box "Autoresize subviews" in the nib for that collection view cell. It will work fine on both iOS 8 and iOS 7.

Comment: No it doesn't. This is an embedded prototype cell.