# Xcode 6 beta4, UIButton is not responsable in collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6.0 beta 4, I find that the buttons in the `UICollectionViewCell` is not response to the tap.

Details as:

```
UICollectionViewController
```

--- `UICollectionViewCell`

------ `UIButton` (`UIButton` has two `autolayout` constraints to put the `UIButton` in vertical center and horizontal center in the `Cell` )

Now make the `cell` size is something like: (300, 1000)

Run the app in iPhone Simulator or device with iOS 7.0 or 7.1.x, the button is not touchable, but test in iOS 8.0 simulator it's OK.
Also if I change the cell `size` to `(300, 200)`, the button works.

I think it's a bug in this Xcode beta version, right?

And where I can fire the bug to Apple?

Comment: You can report a bug via this site: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoresizing issue of UICollectionViewCell in Storyboard prototype cell (Xcode 6 Beta 3 deploying to iOS 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-in-storyboard-prototype-cell-xcode-6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have forgotten to set an autoresizingMask for the contentView of a UICollectionViewCell

this fix it

```
self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, it works. I have report the bug to apple

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is not actually a bug, but an incompatibility issue of targeting iOS 7  devices using Xcode 6. [ecotax's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-contentviews-frame-in-storyboard-pro) describes this in more detail, but here is the response from Apple DTS:

> In iOS 7, cells’ content views sized themselves via autoresizing masks. In iOS 8, this was changed, cells stopped using the autoresizing masks and started sizing the content view in layoutSubviews. If a nib is encoded in iOS 8 and then decode it on iOS 7, you’ll have a content view without an autoresizing mask and no other means by which to size itself. So if you ever change the frame of the cell, the content view won’t follow.
>
> Apps being deploying back to iOS 7 will have to work around this by sizing the content view itself, adding autoresizing masks, or adding constraints.

Alexey's solution above will do the trick though:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   // Fix for iOS 7 devices targeted using Xcode 6.
   self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```