# Resizing UIViews within UICollectionViewCell in iOS7 using iOS8 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have an UICollectionView with subviews in the cells. They don't resize in iOS7 using the iOS8 SDK. When running the app on iOS8 seems to be ok

It seems that in the drawForRect of the subviews the frame is not resized as it's all the time returning the same value.

I am using auto layout attaching the the subviews to the edge of the cells.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

This is the solution. I will keep this in case it's easier to find for you with my question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25768887/1523444

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoresizing issue of UICollectionViewCell in Storyboard prototype cell (Xcode 6 Beta 3 deploying to iOS 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-in-storyboard-prototype-cell-xcode-6)

Comment: Are you using custom CollectionView cell?

Comment: Yes, @PradipVanparia

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with iOS7.
Its work for me.
Put this method in custom cell class.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```

Comment: Apple changed how the autoresizingMask is set in Xcode 6 xib files making it incompatible when running on iOS 7.  This is the easiest way to fix it.