# XCode 6.0.1 ios 7 Autolayout

Tags: ios7, ios8, xcode6

I have found that applications built in XCode 6 for ios 7 have different behavior from same apps built for ios 8. There is something wrong with autolayout constraints. For example some bottom and trailing spaces won't work if I build app in XCode 6 for ios 7 both in sumulator or device, but apps correctly work if i build them in XCode 6 for ios 8 or in XCode 5 for ios 7. So i think there are some troubles for ios 7 when you build with XCode 6. If anyone has the same issue and how can it be resolved?

Comment: same here, still looking for solution

Comment: Found the solution for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/25884832/709515

Answer (score 1):

> In iOS 7, cells’ content views sized themselves via autoresizing
>   masks. In iOS 8, this was changed, cells stopped using the
>   autoresizing masks and started sizing the content view in
>   layoutSubviews. If a nib is encoded in iOS 8 and then decode it on iOS
>   7, you’ll have a content view without an autoresizing mask and no
>   other means by which to size itself. So if you ever change the frame
>   of the cell, the content view won’t follow.
>
> Apps being deploying back to iOS 7 will have to work around this by
>   sizing the content view itself, adding autoresizing masks, or adding
>   constraints. I guess this means that it's not a bug in XCode 6, but an
>   incompatibility between the iOS 8 SDK and iOS 7 SDK, which will hit
>   you if you upgrade to Xcode 6, because it will automatically start
>   using the iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: You should add the source link for this to make it more credible.

Comment: The question needs to have a solution. Others  might look for the same question, not finding an answer. Comment is not the place to put it.