# How to fix the black bars appearing on a iPhone 5/5s with iOS7?

Tags: ios7, interface-builder, ios8, xcode6

I started a new Xcode6 project settings iOS8 as the deployment target. I designed the screens in a storyboard, disabling autolayout and using the auto-resizing masks. Everything works perfectly on iPhone 5/5s/6/6+ using iOS8.

Now I wanted to enable support for iOS7, setting the deployment target to that version...however if I run the app in the iPhone 5/5s sim with iOS7, the layout is totally broken: there are black strips at the top and the bottom of every screen, and many other views are bad positioned.

Since it works fine on iOS8...what can it be?

Comment: ok, so the black bars were there because I was missing the launch image for iPhone5 on iOS7 (it needs a static image and not the xib like in iOS8). However I still don't understand why the rest of the layout is broken. It's mostly the layout of cells inside a ViewCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in my comment above, I was missing two things:

1) the launch image for iPhone 5/5s on iOS7. It was working on iOS8 because iOS8 supports a dynamic xib file for the launch screen. The project had the xib but not the static image to support iOS7

2) it appears the cell's contentView (for collection views, and I suppose tableviews) is "borken" in xcode6/iOS6. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-contentviews-frame-in-storyboard-pro) explains how to fix it.