# UICollectionView cell sizing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

The right column pictures get cut off. For example, the pink lion on the right should be basically symmetrical, but is obviously not. This is how I configure the imageCell.

```
func configureCellWithImage(image: Image){
    let iV = self.imageView
    iV.setImageWithURL(image.thumbURL)
    if(image.aspectRatio < 1.62){
        iV.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    }else{
        iV.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    }

}
```

And this is how I return the size of the cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize.init(width: screenSize.width/2 - 1, height: screenSize.width/2 * 1.62 - 1)
    return size
}
```

Help appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

I don't know why the UIView is there with the width of 201. It should be 159. How would I access this view? I should only have the CollectionView, imageCell and the UIImageView.

[image]

Comment: are you sure, your collection view layout `minimumInteritemSpacing` is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase value of right attribute in "section insets" of collection view in story board

[Scale section of Collection View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qzoD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have used ScreenSize in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method, this is wrong, you will use the collectionView width size, use my below code,

```
    func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
        {
            return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.frame.width/2)-5, height: ((self.collectionView!.frame.width/2) * 1.62) - 1)
        }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 0.0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 0.0
    }
```

hope its helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. It looks like the compiler is creating another UIView. Please see edit on my OP.

Comment: you will set the imageView in `UICollectionViewCell` and set constraints in ImageView, its automatically change the size in image, then use my code, its will work.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this post after searching more.

[Autoresizing issue of UICollectionViewCell contentView's frame in Storyboard prototype cell (Xcode 6, iOS 8 SDK) happens when running on iOS 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-contentviews-frame-in-storyboard-pro)

The solution was to put

```
self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
```