# ios CollectionView, autoresizing mask does not work, when I change the cell size programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, xib

**Update:**
I got the answer from here

[Autoresizing issue of UICollectionViewCell contentView's frame in Storyboard prototype cell (Xcode 6, iOS 8 SDK) happens when running on iOS 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-contentviews-frame-in-storyboard-pro)

And here

[UICollectionView cell subviews do not resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303100/uicollectionview-cell-subviews-do-not-resize)

At both the places we can get the same answer of two lines of code.

**You can not see the CollectionView's contentView in XIB but it is there. So just apply the code.**

```
self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

In
My ios App,

In my CollectionView,

**I need a different cell sizes for iPhone 4s and iPhone 6. I am setting it programmatically, here autoresizing mask does not work.**

Below is the code,

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CGFloat itemWidth=(self.view.frame.size.width-cellMarginForCollectionView)/2;

    return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth);
}
```

And results come like below,

[image: Label cuts down.]

The problem is label cuts down, and imgeview also cut at Right side.

Comment: did you set constraints to imageview ?

Comment: I am not using Auto Layout.

Comment: @ArpitBParekh may be you can give a device specific value for your cell

Comment: Means I have given a device specific width, height for the cell..Second thing I can do is, have a seperate XIB, for different devices....

Comment: I got the answer from here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-contentviews-frame-in-storyboard-pro

Comment: And from here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303100/uicollectionview-cell-subviews-do-not-resize same answer at both the places.