# Swift : UICollectionView Cell can not update frame when implement sizeForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

when i implement below code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{

    let cellW = (ScreenWidth - 10 - 10 - 30) / 4

    return CGSize(width: cellW, height: cellW * 1.5 )

}
```

by using sizeForItemAt method , i can draw frame what i want , but my custom collectionview cell can not update as wise , where did i miss , plz help me !!

[my custom cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9WYp.jpg)

[debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fgxn.jpg)

Comment: Add constraint for your image to leading/trailing/top to superView? And add missing constraints for the bottom view?

Comment: i aready did add constraint for my imageview and label , it's seem collectionview cell's problem , maybe i missing something  in awakefromNib? 

http://imgur.com/a/6N9qC

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/XOVTn  this is my storyboard collectionview cell frame

Comment: Did you write that you implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in you class declaration?

Comment: yes i did  implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate , so that i can draw the area  (see in debug view : https://imgur.com/a/TyjOr)

Answer (score 1):

i fix it by this ref
[UICollectionView cell subviews do not resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303100/uicollectionview-cell-subviews-do-not-resize)

thanks guys , at frist still have problem with my Cell.imageview , can not shape-round as i want , and i create a class for imageview ,below:

```
class CellImageView: UIImageView {
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let radius: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

and anything work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

For me in iOS 13, I have fixed by first `estimatedItemSize` to `.zero` and set the `itemSize` like;

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
 layout.estimatedItemSize = .zero
 layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 80)
}
```